# XGBoost multiple eval_metric in Sagemaker

Tags: python, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to add multiple evaluation metrics to an XGBoost training job using Sagemaker, documentation says it is possible (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.rst#learning-task-parameters):

> User can add multiple evaluation metrics. Python users: remember to
> pass the metrics in as list of parameters pairs instead of map, so
> that latter eval_metric won't override previous one

The documentation hasn't any code examples But I have tried many ways to do it(including the simple passing them as a list, ex: eval_metric=['mae', 'merror']), but I just cannot find a syntax that works. Any hints?

Comment: from what you quoted from the documentation, I am trying to understand what they mean as list of parameters pairs. 
Some guess:


```[[eval_metric, 'rmse'], [eval_metric, 'rmsle']]
[['rmse', my_rmse_function], ['rmsle', my_rmsle_function]]```
I am quite sure about the format but not the content for each pair

Comment: @CAPSLOCK right, I'm struggling to understand what they mean, I've tried list of lists(as yours), list of tuples, list of key:value pairs and none worked, documentation should have code examples.

Comment: From the comment I am guessing that the solution I posted below did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sagemaker SDK implementation of XGBOOST follows `dmlc/xgboost`. So you can just pass the `eval_metric` as you would with xgboost.ai.

```
xgb_model.fit(trainData, targetVar, early_stopping_rounds=10, 
eval_metric=['mae', 'merror', 'aucpr'], eval_set=[(valData, valTarget)])
```

In the example above, we are passing three evaluation metrics. However, if you are trying to pass custom metrics then the above implementation wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Did you tried it?  reason why I ask is that was the first thing I tried with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution (untested, found [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html#setting-parameters))

```
param['eval_metric'] = ['auc', 'ams@0']

# alternatively:
# plst = param.items()
# plst += [('eval_metric', 'ams@0')]
```

I guess that if you want more than two, you would go for the list of pairs

```
plst = param.items()
plst += [('eval_metric', 'ams@0'), ('eval_metric', 'auc'), ('eval_metric', 'rmse')]
```

or

```
param['eval_metric'] = [['auc', 'ams@0'], ['rmsle', 'rmse']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of unintuitive and definitely not well-documented, but you need to enter it as a single comma-separated string like this:

```
hyperparameters={
    "objective": 'binary:logistic',
    "num_round": 50,
    "max_delta_step": 1,
    "max_depth": 5,
    "alpha": 10,
    "eta": 0.2,
    "gamma": 2,
    "subsample": 0.8,
    "eval_metric": 'aucpr,f1_binary',
}
```

You can see how it works here:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/blob/master/src/sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit/hyperparameter_validation.py#L173